# How to get the final current working directory of a child process?

Tags: process, cwd

If I spawn off a child process, I can access its working directory (in a not-very-cross-platform way) any time while it's alive by examining `/proc/<PID>/cwd`. But what are my options if I want to know its final location on exit?

I've tried watching `/proc/<PID>/` after death, but the directory vanishes as soon as the child does, even if the parent's camped out there. And this may not even be a concern, but that seems a bit fragile if my child manages to exit before I can grab its PID and read the symlink.

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes, or because the parent needs to know this information, or what?

Comment: @StephenHarris The parent wants to know. In my specific case, child processes can't change the working directory of their parent but I figure the parent can just follow the childrens' leads if it wants. Just keeping an eye on the children seems like a simple way to do it.